# Java Arraylist size declaration and performance

Tags: java, arrays, performance, arraylist

Consider the following Java code (complete, compiles and runs fine).

The code creates an array containing 5,000,000 integers (1 to 5 million), loops over it, and creates an ArrayList of the perfect squares it finds. Perfect squares are detected using a naive technique, and not bit manipulation, but that is not the focus of the issue at hand.

Mathematically, between 1 and 5M, there are 2236 perfect squares. So the ArrayList that the perfect squares are being put into will have a final size of 2236.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PerfSquares {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> perfectSquares(int[] arr) {
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //  ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(arr.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            double root = Math.sqrt(arr[i]);
            int irt = (int) Math.floor(root);
            if (irt * irt == arr[i]) {
                al.add(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return al;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[5000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = i + 1;
        }

        long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
        perfectSquares(arr);
        long e = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(e - s);
    }
}
```

---

I'd like to focus on the declaration of the ArrayList. These two lines, one of which is commented out:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(arr.length);
```

When I run with the first declaration (**without** the size explicitly supplied), the timediff I see is:

```
~96 milliseconds.
```

When I run with the second declaration (**with** the size explicitly supplied), the timediff increases to:

```
~105 milliseconds
```

---

Question:

**Why is this behavior so? Shouldn't the second case (size supplied) be faster?**

As per my understanding, in the first case, when we omit the size parameter to the ArrayList creation, behind the scenes an array of length 10 will be initialized. And when this capacity is exceeded, a new array with a larger capacity (not sure how much larger) will be allocated, and the previous elements will be copied over.

For 2236 elements and no initial size being specified, this "cap exceeded - allocate new - copy over - append more till cap" cycle should repeat many times, slowing it down.

Consequently, I was expecting the size supplied declaration to be faster - Since the allocation will happen once, and there will be no capacity exceeding / new array creation and copying over happening.

Or is this basically so because 2236 appends to an ArrayList, even with all the cap-exceeds-copy-over cycles, will still be faster than creating an ArrayList of size 5,000,000?

Comment: Running this just once, with such a bad precision of System.currentTimeMillis(), and obtaining such a small difference, leads to meaningless results. Execute it 1000 times, and then start measuring, with System.nanoTime(), for the next 1000 executions, and then average the results.

Comment: Instead of creating the `ArrayList` with the full array size, try to use `(int) Math.sqrt(arr.size())`, which is approximately the number o f perfect squares. Add a few if you want to be sure.

Comment: I would think of using a LinkedList here.

Comment: @SidCool bad idea. When we talk about performance, LinkedList is *never* an option.

Comment: @leventov that statement makes no sense. How about when elements are to be removed from the list? LinkedList still slower?  ArrayList is faster accessing nth element, but apart from that it makes little difference, and linkedlist benefits of items are to be removed or inserted. To say one is faster than the other, with no context, is incorrect.

Comment: @Aaron: With `LinkedList` even appending and iterating are much slower (by a factor of 2 plus the GC overhead). There's you only one operation where it's good: Removal at the `Iterator`'s position. That's close to nothing. While there are good use cases for `LinkedList`, they're much rarer than most people expect.

Comment: @maaartinus Well appending and inserting are two different kettles of fish. I'm just saying that  "LinkedList is never an option" is a bit of a sweeping statement :D

Comment: @maaartinus Although i've been reading and perhaps my objections are actually invalid! http://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/why-you-should-never-ever-ever-use-linked-list-in-your-code-again/    Thanks for the steer.

Comment: @Aaron I even think addition LinkedList to the standard Java API was a mistake. LinkedList is only appropriate in very rare and specific situations. During my 6 years Java experience *I've never used it*. Unlike TreeMap/Set, Deque and other data structures. [On Github](https://github.com/search?l=java&q=LinkedList&ref=searchresults&type=Code) LinkedList is used more often, than TreeMap, TreeSet, Deque and ArrayDeque *put together*. That is disappointing.

Comment: @leventov I've used it where it matches the domain model more naturally than using an array/list. [Java]Performance is rarely an issue in the work I tend to do, where DB access / network latency is normally the bottleneck. Thanks for the conversation though - it's clearer to me now that it only really makes sense where the domain model suggests it as a natural fit.

Comment: @leventov LinkedList is important when the operation involves lots of insertions, because it's a doubly linked list.

Comment: just a note: An ArrayList always initializes with a size corresponding to a power of two. When you specify an initial size, it will actually initialize to the next higher power of two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating an arraylist of 5 million, so clearly it's slower. You only need 2236. That's alot of waste.

If you change the size of your array list to 10k for example you'll see the time difference shrink.

To make it simpler, just try this test, multiple times, in different orders -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   long timea = System.currentTimeMillis();

   // ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(5000000);


    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - timea);

}
```

You'll see that initialising an arraylist to 5 million takes around 10ms (on my macbook), while the one with no default size is pretty much instantaneous. This is the same no mater which order you test.

Comment: It is not slower at all, if you benchmark properly you'll end up with a difference below 2%.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut It is slower - run the tests and see.

Comment: Run the caliper benchmark and see the result for yourself: https://gist.github.com/thomasjungblut/7196135 Result: 99.6 ms vs. 101 ms. Copying at this small numbers is just as expensive as directly allocating a much larger array.

Comment: Do all those iterations run in the same VM though? If so that's a different test - running the above code once at a time it's clear that no matter which order you test (initialised list first, or just plain list first), the one sized at 5000000 takes noticeably longer at least 9 times out of ten. The OP finds it unintuitive - the reason is the massive allocation.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your method of measurement is flawed. Under these circumstances, however, measurement is not easy, because there for such large array allocation each following new may be slower.

As for your problem: memory allocation (and even deallocation) is an expensive operation. Not when you use `new` - nowadays vms are quite optimized for many small short-lived objects - but mostly whenever the JVM has to reserve/allocate (aka `malloc()`) memory on the lower, system level. Moreover, the memory allocation time also depends on the amount of memory allocated - the more you need, the longer it will take.

In your case: the amount of perfect squares is AFAIR easy to compute. Just use `(Math.sqrt(arr.length) + 1)` to determine the initial `ArrayList` size and get the size exactly right immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Because memory allocation is generally a slow operation. I counted the number of allocations and new element for both cases.

In this case

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

You have only 15 allocations for 8317 elements in total. And in this case

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(arr.length);
```

you have a single allocation for 5000000 elements.

Comment: It looks like its the relative size of the allocation that is expensive, rather than the allocation itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `add()` on an `ArrayList` which is already full, it grows automatically by 50 %. So it will be quickly big enough and there will not be so many memory allocations.